# get_posts return posts by all author even if post_author is set to a specific ID

Tags: wordpress

I have a query to get custom post type "date" posts of the current user. The query has some meta_query condition that works fine, but the current user filter doesn't work at all...
I don't know if it is important but this query run as part of an ajax function. I've verified that current user is correctly defined.
Here the query:

```
$curr_user = wp_get_current_user();
$date = array('2015-11-20', '2015-11-30')
$query_date_arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'date',
    'post_author' => $curr_user->ID,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(//date singole comprese nel periodo $date
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-date',
                'value' => $date,
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-date-end',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        array( //periodi compresi nel periodo $date
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-date',
                'value' => $date,
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-date-end',
                'value' => $date,
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            ),
        ), 
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids',
);
$dates_to_be_deleted = get_posts( $query_date_arg );
```

This query should return an array of posts ids of the current user that match the meta_query condition.
The issue is that I'm getting the posts ids of ALL the users not only the posts of the current one.

It is a wordpress 4.3.1 bug or, as I think..., I have some error in the query?

I'll appreciate any help!

thanks
daniele

Comment: Change the parameter named 'post_author' in the query arguments to 'author'.

Comment: Thanks! I wasted 2 our on this stupid error... In a previos version of the function the "post_author" parameter was used by the wp_insert_post() function... When I rewrote the function logic I hadn't update the query parameter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Please Change the Parameter name 'post_author', use only 'author'.

```
'author'    => get_current_user_id(),
```

Thank you !!

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.